# Edge browser Speech Synthesis stop working after call speak with some empty paragraph text using Xiaoxiao voice

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, speech-synthesis, chinese-locale

I'm using `SpeechSynthesis` APIs on Microsoft Edge browser. But something went wrong...
Here is what I have got so far (already minimized to what can reproduce the result)

I had Chinese language pack installed on Windows. The Edge browser also have some online voices available. You may need the same environments installed to make the following snippet working.

```js
const speak = (p, voice) => {
  p.split('\n').forEach(text => {
    const ssu = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
    ssu.lang = 'zh-CN';
    ssu.voice = voice;
    speechSynthesis.speak(ssu);
    console.log(ssu);
  });
};

let voices = [];
const getVoice = voiceURI => {
  const voice = voices.find(voice => voice.voiceURI === voiceURI);
  return voice;
};

const huihuiURI = "Microsoft Huihui - Chinese (Simplified, PRC)";
const xiaoxiaoURI = "Microsoft Xiaoxiao Online (Natural) - Chinese (Mainland)";
const voicesChanged = () => {
  voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  if (getVoice(huihuiURI) && getVoice(xiaoxiaoURI)) {
    mainarea.hidden = false;
  }
};
speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', voicesChanged);
voicesChanged();

huihui.addEventListener('click', () => {
  speak('第一段\n……\n第二段', getVoice(huihuiURI));
});
xiaoxiao.addEventListener('click', () => {
  speak('第一段\n……\n第二段', getVoice(xiaoxiaoURI));
});
```

```html
<main id=mainarea hidden>
<button id=huihui>Microsoft Huihui</button>
<button id=xiaoxiao>Microsoft Xiaoxiao Online</button>
</main>
```

The script first wait two speech voices available, and then show two buttons. When certain button is clicked, it try to speak texts with specified voice.

When I click the button Huihui, it works correctly. But when I try the voice Xiaoxiao, only first paragraph is spoken. The Xiaoxiao voice refused to speak the ssu without any words, and simply stop working instead of skip it and continue to the next one. I'm not sure why this happened. (You may need to reload / reopen the webpage to test different buttons.)

The text going to speak will come from user input (out of my control) in my project. So I don't think I can strip empty words before sending them to SpeechSynthesis APIs.

I want to know what's wrong here and how can I fix this, so I can use Xiaoxiao voice to speak the whole text.

---

In case it matters: I'm using Microsoft Edge Version 92.0.902.67 (Official build) (64-bit) on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1151].

Comment: Why do you have '.......' ? This is where it fails.

Comment: @Frazer 

The text going to speak will come from user input (out of my control) in my project. So I don't think I can strip empty words before sending them to SpeechSynthesis APIs. It will also fail with some other texts, "……" here is only an example.

Answer (score 1):

I make some tests and find that **the issue happens on some versions of Windows 10**. On Windows 10 version 20H2, OS build 19042.630, it works well with both voices. But on Windows 10 version 1909, OS build 18363.1679, I can reproduce the same issue. The Edge versions are the same in both machines, which is 92.0.902.67 (Official build) (64-bit). I think the issue may be related with OS builds.

In the Xiaoxiao voice not working scenario, I observed that it can't speak paragraphs with only symbols like the paragraph only has "......", then it stops to speak the remaining things. According to this, I think the only workaround is not speaking the article paragraph by paragraph, but speaking the whole article for once.

Then in the code, you don't need to split the text by `\n` and you can edit the first part of the js code like below. Then it can speak the whole text with Xiaoxiao voice:

```
const speak = (p, voice) => {
        const ssu = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(p);
        ssu.lang = 'zh-CN';
        ssu.voice = voice;
        speechSynthesis.speak(ssu);
        console.log(ssu);
};
```

Comment: Though I don't know what is the length limit of SpeechSynthesis API is. (I didn't find one in any documents) I have tried to feed a 350KiB novel to speak API directly. And it simply report an error. So I have to split it into small parts somehow. And as far as I can see, using line breaks (with some more hard limit if we encounter a very long line) is simplest I can do. Which is language independent (It doesn't need to be restrict on Chinese Mandarin) and without needing any knowledge about the text.

Comment: When you feed a novel, what error does it report?

Comment: Form [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/text#value): *The maximum length of the text that can be spoken in each utterance is 32,767 characters.* Does the user input length need so long? Besides, if you need to use line breaks, I think it's exceedingly rare that a paragraph only has symbols. As long as the paragraph has a normal word or letter, the voice can continue to speak.

Comment: @YuZhou It would not be rare when some novels is longer than 32k characters. And I did get many paragraphs contain only texts like `「……」`. So I had to write some workaround to make it continue reading novels for me...